# получение данных из базы с использованием websoket

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, ratchet

Использую php, ratchet. Строю интерфейс, отображающий активность операторов в интерфейсе.Часть данных, я получаю на лету, через тот же вебсокет, а часть пишется в базу по не контролируемому каналу. Мне нужно отображать изменения статусов, которые записаны в базу мимо вебсокета. Соответственно, нужно постоянно мониторить в базу. Адекватная погрешность в отображении данных 1-2 секунды. Если больше, то ценность этих данных теряется. Вопрос в селующем:
1) Установив подключение к БД в вебсокете можно дёргать записи из базы каждую секунду или две. Не слишком ли это напряжно, так часто дёргать базу? как можно этого избежать?
2)Есть ли другой способ отлавливать изменения в базе? Как оперативно реагировать на внешние воздействия, учитывая, что php не умеет колбэки.
3) Крон не рассматриваю. И так миллион всяких мелочей происходит. Мало мне одного, я уже два демона прикрутил к системе. Мне проще как-то реализовать опрос в рамках существующего демона, но ума не приложу, как? Если спрашивать базу каждые пару секунд это почти ддос базы.

Куда посмотреть? Какие варианты? Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Comment: *Не слишком ли это напряжно, так часто дёргать базу?* Один запрос в секунду? несерьёзно... если в таблице есть признак актуальных данных (скажем, штамп времени), объём выборки невелик (пролезет на клиента гораздо менее чем за секунду, с учётом загрузки сервера БД и канала пишущими на него клиентами), и есть необходимые для эффективного выполнения запроса индексы. *это почти ддос базы* Для ДДОС надо хотя бы на пару порядков чаще... *Есть ли другой способ отлавливать изменения в базе?* В рамках MySQL - увы, штатных нет.

Comment: Так, мне ту нужно уточнение. Я знаю, что чем меньше запросов к базе, тем лучше. Это актуально в рамках количества подключений, но не запросов? Если у меня одно подключение к бд дергается раз в секунду по 18 часов в день, это нормальный режим работы для бд. А если ко мне приходит один юзер в секунду и дёргает страницу, создавая дополнительные подключения к бд это не хорошо. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: *Я знаю, что чем меньше запросов к базе, тем лучше.* Ну да, оптимум - вообще не спрашивать :) *Это актуально в рамках количества подключений, но не запросов?* Подключения расходуют ресурсы, причём эксклюзивно: оперативку на приёмные буферы, и канал обмена. Запросы же используют, причём разделяемо, ресурсы на обработку - оперативную память и процессор.

Comment: *Если ... А если* У тебя всё равно один клиент - в первом случае приложение, во втором скрипт-сервер. Другой вопрос, что скрипт-сервер для формирования одной страницы может открыть несколько подключений и в каждом выполнить несколько запросов - но ведь и приложение может вести себя точно так же... так что какой тут разговор о правильности? думай о том, справляется сервер с нагрузкой или нет, а если нет - то каких ресурсов ему недостаточно, и что делать - добавить недостающего ресурса или оптимизировать, снизив потребление этого ресурса.